# Install OpenSSL 1.0 package on Fedora 34

Tags: openssl, fedora

I am developing in C++ with a tool that requires OpenSSL 1.0, but Fedora 34 includes OpenSSL 1.1 (which causes numerous errors)

Is it possible to install OpenSSL 1.0 alongside 1.1 ?  If so, how - I can't find a matching package

Comment: Fedora hasn't used OpenSSL 1.0.X since at least Fedora 26. [OpenSSL discusses](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes) a compatibility layer that may allow you to use version 1.0 API with version 1.1.

Comment: Unfortunately, that compatibility layer was removed in Fedora 34. I suppose building the compat package yourself might be worth it, but you will have to keep on maintaining it to pick up the security fixes. Though [uspstream OpenSSL 1.0 has declared it End of Life](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2018/05/18/new-lts/). @TSG, you might be better off switching to another distro that has OpenSSL 1.0 (CentOS 7?), or, better get a new version of the tool that works against a version of OpenSSL that's not EOL.